# What is an application that sorts Android apps on the Google Play Store by number of current users?

Tags: linux, android, web-apps, play-store

What is an Android, Linux, or web application that has a feature which can be described by the following user story?

> The user is presented with a list of apps from the Google Play Store. The apps are sorted from most installed (currently) to least installed (currently).

I am *not* looking for an application that sorts Android apps based on the total number of downloads during their lifetimes.

Comment: I suspect that you are looking to find the most __used__ rather then just installed applications the problem is that unless the app reports somewhere how often it is actually used _a violation of the users privacy in itself_ then this information will not be available - if you would like this sort of information switch to iOS or WinMobile and put up with the prying/spying.

Comment: I think what @SteveBarnes is saying is that you can find out how many downloads an app has had, but, since many might try it once and delete it, or leave it installed but never actually use it, the bets that you can hope for is number of downloads, but not number of current users.